# Handling a click and a tap but not a scroll

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember.js-view

I have an `Ember.View` that handles both the `click` and `touchEnd` events, for both desktop and mobile interactions.

Unfortunately, `touchEnd` also gets fired when scrolling, which is not intended. How do I handle the click and tap, but avoid the scroll event?

```
Ember.View.extend({
  click: function() {
    // not handled in a mobile browser
  },
  touchEnd: function() {
    // handled in a mobile browser, but unfortunately also on scroll
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you considered using Modernizr to detect whether or not your end-user is on a touch screen?

Comment: Why not just use click and use fast click. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-fastclick

Comment: @blessenm you should make your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding handlers for both `click` and `touchEnd`, use the [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) library. Now you just need to add a handler for the `click` event. If your using ember-cli, there is an [addon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-fastclick) for this.